# How to run Windows Nano Server container from Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, docker-for-windows, nano-server

My host is running Windows 10 Pro, version 2004, build 19041.1052. I have the Hyper-V and Containers Windows Features enabled. I am running Docker Desktop 4.0.0 (67817), Engine 20.10.8. I have chosen the engine for Windows Containers. I have pulled the Nano Server image tagged `2004-amd64` (build 19041.1165). I have a Ryzen 9 CPU. When I try to run the image with this command from a PowerShell run as Administrator:

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:2004-amd64 --rm cmd.exe
```

I get this error:

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\DOCKER\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 
52d69ec5645099a0c729a285c1192f4cb909f167d36efa4cf60cf9cc82c6cd56 encountered an error 
during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot 
find the file specified. (0x2).
```

Searching this error yields a few questions from people having trouble building an image. None that I have seen have an accepted answer, and none of the suggestions seem relevant to me (most are focused on editing the Dockerfile).

I'm not married to this image tag. I would like to run some version of Nano Server or Server Core. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Today, after pulling and running `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:latest` and `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:2004-amd64` (both of which worked), I am now able to run the image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:2004-amd64` that was giving me trouble yesterday. I don't know what fixed it. Maybe some image layer was missing that got filled in by pulling another image using the same layer?